# Is "Similar Entries" or "Similar by Terms" a better module for listing nodes similar to the one the user is currently viewing?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, related-content

I'm looking at these two modules for a "Related articles" style listing:

- Similar by Terms
- Similar Entries

Any opinions on either of them? I have a tag system set up so searching by terms would be fine, but it hasn't been updated as recently as the other module. How reliable is "Similar Entries"? Anyone have any field experience with either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Comparison of Similiar / Relevant by term block modules](http://drupal.org/node/323329), Similar By Terms seems preferable because

- There is a version for Drupal 7.
- It has been updated at the end of July (Similar Entries has been updated on May 2009).
- It caches the results.

If I would have to choose a different module, I would choose Relevant Content, which has also a CCK field that allows you to put a list of related nodes in each nodes you want.

Comment: Similar by Terms it is then! Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

I would also take a look at [Content recommendation modules wiki](http://groups.drupal.org/node/12347) in the Similar Module Review on groups.drupal.org.